# How to update state of page when pagination is enabled?

Tags: reactjs, laravel, redux

What is the best way to solve problem like this:

- we got paginated results on our page (for example, 10 blog posts)
- we click LIKE button on some post
- how to update new state of page using Laravel & React?

Laravel doesn't support pagination with POST request. Should we send another GET request to refresh our page's state?

Comment: Are you sure you can't send post request?

Comment: Are you sure you need to use Laravel's pagination here? I thihk you should POST or even UPDATE the post ID you like and refetch posts list i order to see that likes appeared on required post.

Answer (score 0):

> Laravel doesn't support pagination with POST request

Pagination are meant to be used in GET request so this has all the sense in the world.

When you make your POST request to update the state of an object (in this case, to like a post), the task should be to persist the change of the state. This shouldn't interfiere with how you refresh your view in order to update the state (visually).

My strategy would be like this:

- The user get the list of posts: GET request of paginated list).
- The user likes a post: POST request to the endpoint that handles this. This won't affect your view. You just have to make sure to get a success response (for example, a 200 response code from your endpoint).
- Update the state of the object "visually": Given the fact that your server has responded that the state of the object has been persisted, you could just mark the post as liked visually, this means apply some classes/CSS to the button for example.
- When the user change of page, or refresh the site, your server will send them all the objects refreshed, so this means that your updated object will have the correct state.